# SQL new daily table based on range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
root@localhost [hatsize]> SELECT COUNT(*) AS C,EventID,Start,End,sysname  FROM complete_ev WHERE type = 's' AND EventID = 6881;
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| C  | EventID | Start               | End                 | sysname |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 26 |    6881 | 2013-09-09 12:00:00 | 2013-09-13 22:00:00 | sv-esx4 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

I want to create a new table with the Count, EventID and sysname, but I want the date to be daily so something like:

```
 26 6881   2013-09-09  sv-esx4
 26 6881   2013-09-10  sv-esx4
 26 6881   2013-09-11  sv-esx4
 26 6881   2013-09-12  sv-esx4
 26 6881   2013-09-13  sv-esx4
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do that? I have tried a few things but haven't come up with the right formula. 
Thanks.

Comment: I am re-reading this now and I think there is an element of your requirement that is not clear.  Are you looking for a TOTAL count of EventID 6881 for each day, not the count of event 6881 per day?  This would yield an identical count for each row.  Is this what you need?  That is a different operation than my answer below (although the answer below will be part of the solution if I am reading this right).

Comment: Yes, apologies. I need a TOTAL count of EventID 6881 for each day. So an identical row, nothing changes daily for each EventID, I just want to have a daily count.

Comment: I have finally pieced together the requirements.  You need a gapless list of dates BETWEEN the start and end date on a single row.  That part would have been helpful to note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a driver table for the date range you are looking for (you could use a sub-query or CTE, but a full-fledged table is worth the effort).  Creating a calendar table will be the best way to do this in terms of performance.  You can find a wide collection of canned SQL scripts to create the calendar table if you need to.  This resource will come in handy all the time so it is well worth the minimal setup effort required.  Assuming you have a calendar table, you can then do the following:

```
SELECT allEvents.totalCount AS C,
  ev.EventID,
  CAST(c.Date AS Date) AS date,
  ev.sysname  
FROM complete_ev ev
RIGHT JOIN calendar c ON c.Date BETWEEN ev.Start AND ev.End
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(EventID) AS totalCount, EventID FROM complete_ev GROUP BY EventID) AS allEvents ON ev.EventID = allEvents.eventID
WHERE ev.type = 's' 
  AND ev.EventID = 6881;
```

That is in fact the ticket.  Good Luck with this.

Comment: Thanks just needed a GROUP BY date at the end. Apologies for the lack of detail in the question.